# How to get posts with votes between two numbers? - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, where-clause, acts-as-votable

I tried this, but it didn't work, it returns all posts

```
Post.where(' -1 < cached_votes_score < 10')
```

although

```
Post.where(' cached_votes_score < 10')
```

works, any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `AND`:

```
Post.where('cached_votes_score > -1').where('cached_votes_score < 10')
```